Power Query : How to pivot table
I really need your help
I want to change the table (table one) from this one

For table one, all the text below Number will go for Manchester, and All Text below text will go for Arsenal. That`s why if you see cell (2, Arsenal) or (5, Arsenal), you will see blank or null cell.
I need table like this one


In Power Query, one method:

Add a custom column that contains the (I assume) teams or null depending on whether the value in the preceding row of Column 1 is a number or not.
Group by each change in a numeric value in Column 1
Pivot each subgroup.
Expand the subtables

Please read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm
Original Data

M CodePaste into advanced editorChange Source to reflect your actual data source
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//Add a shifted column so as to be able to compare current row of 
//  Column1 with the row above
//Could also do this by adding an Index column, but this method is usually faster
    #"Add Shifted Column" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(Source) & 
        {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(Source[Column1])}),

//Add a column which enters the relevant "Team" in a custom column1
    #"Add Team Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Shifted Column", "Team", each 
        if not (try Number.From([Column1]))[HasError] then null 
        else if (try Number.From([Column1]))[HasError] and not (try Number.From([Column2]))[HasError] then "Manchester"
        else "Arsenal", type nullable text),

//Remove Column2 (the "Shifted" column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Team Column",{"Column2"}),

//Group by the numeric value in Column 1
// Then Pivot each subtable
//Note use of GroupKind.Local and the optional 5th argument of the Table.Group function
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Column1"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_, List.Distinct(List.RemoveNulls([Team])),"Team","Column1" ),
            type table[Column1=number, Manchester=nullable text, Arsenal=nullable text]    }
        }, GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=> try Number.From(y[Column1]) otherwise 0),

//Expand the tables
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Pivot", {"Manchester", "Arsenal"})
in
    #"Expanded Pivot"

Results

